# LXC: exposed file from host has 000 permissions in rootfs dir

Tags: filesystems, lxc

I have the following in the `/var/lib/lxc/container1/config` so my container can see the file from the host.

```
lxc.mount.entry = /etc/someconf.conf etc/someconf.conf none bind,create=file 0 0
```

I can see it in the container and it has `644` permission there however this is what I see from the host.

```
root@node01:~# ls -l /var/lib/lxc/container1/rootfs/etc/someconf.conf 
---------- 1 root root 0 Jul  16 11:29 /var/lib/lxc/container1/rootfs/etc/someconf.conf
```

Do you know why is this, how to fix it or if there is a better way altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You see the base file that was created the first time, as requested (`create=file`) because it didn't exist, over which a bind mount will be applied.

In the container namespace, this empty file won't be seen because it's overriden with the actual file which is host's `/etc/someconf.conf` mounted over it. Yes you can bind mount a directory over a directory, *or* a file over a file.

To have an actual view of the filesystem(s) as seen by the container but still from the host, you can use the `/proc/[pid]/root/` shortcut that will give a view as seen by a process with PID [pid] (as seen on host) that is in the mount namespace of the container.

The `lxc-info` can be used to programmatically get such PID (the container's init PID seen as PID 1 inside the container). For a running container called `foo` the following command outputs (only) its PID as seen from host:

```
lxc-info -H -p -n foo
```

So to see the file from the container's point of view, but still from the host, the full command becomes:

```
ls -l /proc/$(lxc-info -H -p -n foo)/root/etc/someconf.conf
```

The same method can be used to move easily files between host and "invisible" filesystems on the container such as *tmpfs* mounted on `/tmp` within the container.